# Documentation pull request review

Tags: github, pull-request, review, github-codereviews

I am used to document code reviews using a software called collaborator (https://smartbear.com/product/collaborator/overview/)

Is there there any way we can create similar reports from GitHub pull request?

[image: The type of report content I am looking for]

Comment: Well, github itself has a promo site for it's code review features
https://github.com/features/code-review, but I'm not sure what feature of this smartbear thing you need specifically when you mean "document PR review"

Comment: Another option would be looking for alternatives. Since nobody really knows what features of smartbear are crucial to you, only you can look and decide yourself. You can check the GitHub [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?category=code-review&query=&type=&verification=) for code review actions.